# Shorten SQL statement not using a common table expression

Tags: sql, oracle

The SQL below is written to return 'open orders'. This was written in a way I could understand but now I would like to try and optimize this and reduce the amount of code.

The SQL below gives me the desired outcome I'm looking for however, I would like to shorten the query without using WITH AS. Any suggestions using UNION or some other nesting method?

```
WITH 
product AS              --filter by dept
  (SELECT item
  , dept
  FROM item_master
  WHERE dept in ('353')
),
open_orders AS          --view of orders in Status A with ordered units > received units
  (SELECT ol.order_no 
  , ol.item
  , ol.location
  , oh.po_type
  , oh.order_type
  , oh.not_before_date
  , oh.not_after_date
  , oh.otb_eow_date
  , SUM(ol.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered
  , SUM(NVL(ol.qty_received,0)) AS qty_received
  FROM ordhead oh
  , ordloc ol
  WHERE oh.order_no = ol.order_no
  AND oh.status = 'A'
  AND ol.qty_ordered  > NVL(ol.qty_received,0)
--  AND ol.order_no in ('18701212')     --optional filter for specific PO's
  GROUP BY ol.order_no
  , ol.item
  , ol.location
  , oh.po_type
  , oh.order_type
  , oh.not_before_date
  , oh.not_after_date
  , oh.otb_eow_date
  ),
allocations AS          --view of all allocations
  (SELECT ah.alloc_no
  , ah.order_no
  , ah.item
  , ad.to_loc
  , NVL(ad.qty_allocated,0) AS qty_allocated
  , NVL(ad.qty_received,0) AS qty_received
  FROM alloc_header ah
  , alloc_detail ad
  WHERE ah.alloc_no = ad.alloc_no
  )
SELECT p.dept       --main query on above views
, oo.order_no
, oo.po_type
, oo.order_type
, oo.not_before_date
, oo.not_after_date
, oo.otb_eow_date
, oo.item
, CASE WHEN oo.po_type = 0 THEN oo.location ELSE aa.to_loc END AS loc
, SUM(oo.qty_ordered) AS order_qty
, CASE WHEN SUM(NVL(aa.qty_allocated,0)) - SUM(NVL(aa.qty_received,0)) = 0 
  THEN SUM(oo.qty_ordered) - SUM(NVL(oo.qty_received,0))
  ELSE SUM(NVL(aa.qty_allocated,0)) - SUM(NVL(aa.qty_received,0))
  END AS open_qty
FROM open_orders oo
, allocations aa
, product p
WHERE oo.order_no = aa.order_no(+)
AND oo.item = aa.item(+)
AND oo.item = p.item
AND (oo.qty_ordered - oo.qty_received) >0
GROUP BY p.dept
, oo.order_no
, oo.po_type
, oo.order_type
, oo.not_before_date
, oo.not_after_date
, oo.otb_eow_date
, oo.item
, CASE WHEN oo.po_type = 0 THEN oo.location ELSE aa.to_loc END
;
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  I don't mind those `CASE` expressions, why do you want to change them?

Comment: _"This was written in a way I could understand but now I would like to try and optimize this and reduce the amount of code"_
So you want to turn code which you understand and that works into code that you don't understand?

Comment: `UNION` is going to be longer than case, and would need to account for multiple scenarios, resulting in a query so long that it would be near unreadable

Comment: My apologies I am looking for a way to write the query without using WITH AS, not CASE WHEN (original post edit).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using Oracle SQL Developer. The reason I would like to avoid WITH AS is because I will be using this in a MicroStrategy FreeForm SQL report and for whatever reason WITH AS does not seem to work but I've gotten UNION on other queries to return successfully

Comment: `WITH .. AS ` is called a common table expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTE's (Common Table Expressions) are just a way of organizing a query by sticking bits of code (that define a "derived" table) at the top that can be reused in the main statement. As such, where `product`, `open_orders`, and `allocations` are mentioned in the `FROM` clause, you can just swap those words out with the code that defines them:

```
SELECT p.dept --main query on above views
    ,
    oo.order_no,
    oo.po_type,
    oo.order_type,
    oo.not_before_date,
    oo.not_after_date,
    oo.otb_eow_date,
    oo.item,
    CASE 
        WHEN oo.po_type = 0
            THEN oo.location
        ELSE aa.to_loc
        END AS loc,
    SUM(oo.qty_ordered) AS order_qty,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(NVL(aa.qty_allocated, 0)) - SUM(NVL(aa.qty_received, 0)) = 0
            THEN SUM(oo.qty_ordered) - SUM(NVL(oo.qty_received, 0))
        ELSE SUM(NVL(aa.qty_allocated, 0)) - SUM(NVL(aa.qty_received, 0))
        END AS open_qty
FROM (
    SELECT ol.order_no,
        ol.item,
        ol.location,
        oh.po_type,
        oh.order_type,
        oh.not_before_date,
        oh.not_after_date,
        oh.otb_eow_date,
        SUM(ol.qty_ordered) AS qty_ordered,
        SUM(NVL(ol.qty_received, 0)) AS qty_received
    FROM ordhead oh,
        ordloc ol
    WHERE oh.order_no = ol.order_no
        AND oh.STATUS = 'A'
        AND ol.qty_ordered > NVL(ol.qty_received, 0)
    --  AND ol.order_no in ('18701212')     --optional filter for specific PO's
    GROUP BY ol.order_no,
        ol.item,
        ol.location,
        oh.po_type,
        oh.order_type,
        oh.not_before_date,
        oh.not_after_date,
        oh.otb_eow_date
    ) oo,
    (
    SELECT ah.alloc_no,
        ah.order_no,
        ah.item,
        ad.to_loc,
        NVL(ad.qty_allocated, 0) AS qty_allocated,
        NVL(ad.qty_received, 0) AS qty_received
    FROM alloc_header ah,
        alloc_detail ad
    WHERE ah.alloc_no = ad.alloc_no
    ) aa,
    (
    SELECT item,
        dept
    FROM item_master
    WHERE dept IN ('353')
    ) p
WHERE oo.order_no = aa.order_no(+)
    AND oo.item = aa.item(+)
    AND oo.item = p.item
    AND (oo.qty_ordered - oo.qty_received) > 0
GROUP BY p.dept,
    oo.order_no,
    oo.po_type,
    oo.order_type,
    oo.not_before_date,
    oo.not_after_date,
    oo.otb_eow_date,
    oo.item,
    CASE 
        WHEN oo.po_type = 0
            THEN oo.location
        ELSE aa.to_loc
        END;
```

This is obviously not shortened (but by a few characters), but I get the sense that "shortening" isn't your requirement. You are trying to get this query to work in a product that doesn't support CTEs.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to work out!